# update column with aggregate function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, aggregate-functions, updates

I want to change this format to codeigniter format which is like

```
this->db->where('','')
```

This is my code

```
$data = "UPDATE dbhpl.hplpb SET hplpb.PEL_4 = (select COUNT(*) FROM pelayanan 
WHERE pelayanan.ID_AREA=hplpb.ID_AREA AND pelayanan.ID_VERIFIKASI='4' 
AND pelayanan.TRANSAKSI='PENYAMBUNGAN BARU' AND pelayanan.ESTIMASI='4' 
AND pelayanan.ID_STATUS='1')";

$this->db->query($data);
```

How can I change it?

Comment: the table name is hplpd and pelayanan. And the table that I want to update is hplpb.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

```
$data = array(
        'ID_VERIFIKASI' => '4',
        'TRANSAKSI' => 'PENYAMBUNGAN BARU',
        'ESTIMASI' => '4',
        'ID_STATUS' => '1'
);

$this->db->where($data)
         ->from('pelayanan')
         ->join('hplpb', 'hplpb.ID_AREA = pelayanan.ID_AREA', 'inner');

$count = $this->db->count_all_results();


$data = array(
    "PEL_4" => $count
);

$this->db->update('hplpb', $data);
```